# How I can make a navbar and tabs with individual content for each tab depend of navbar item?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to make different content in the tabs for each navbar item. When I select `Navbar1` and go to `Tab one` or `Tab two` or whatever, I want to show a text. When I switch to `Navbar2` in navbar and select `Tab one`, `Tab two` etc.. I want to show a different content.

I'll show the code if necessary, but it's just android-studio default navbar drawer and I added tabs fragments.

Can you please give me any directions on how to proceed in regards to tabs fragments, mainactivity, navbar?

EDIT(Code and SS added):

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLBi5.jpg

**MainActivity.java**

```
package cf.hazzu.bacalaureat;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager Pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        tabpagerAdapter Tabpageradapter = new tabpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Pager.setAdapter(Tabpageradapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(Pager);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_donate) {
            Intent viewIntent =
                    new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://hazzu.cf/app/"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_info) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_one) {
            setTitle("Navbar 1");

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_two) {
            setTitle("Navbar 2");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_three) {
            setTitle("Navbar 3");
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_smoke) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Some text, idk...";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

**tabpagerAdapter.java**

```
package cf.hazzu.bacalaureat;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class tabpagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] tabarray = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
    Integer tabnumber = 3;
    public tabpagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabarray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tab_one tab1 = new tab_one();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                tab_two tab2 = new tab_two();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                tab_three tab3 = new tab_three();
                return tab3;

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabnumber;
    }
}
```

**tab_one.java**

```
package cf.hazzu.bacalaureat;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class tab_one extends Fragment {


    public tab_one() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

**tab_two.java**

```
package cf.hazzu.bacalaureat;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class tab_two extends Fragment {


    public tab_two() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_two, container, false);
    }

}
```

**tab_three.java**

```
package cf.hazzu.bacalaureat;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class tab_three extends Fragment {


    public tab_three() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_three, container, false);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab One" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab Two" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab Three" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**fragment_tab_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tab_one">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/screen_tab1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_tab_two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tab_two">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/screen_tab2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**menu/activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_one"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_font_download_black_24dp"
            android:title="Navbar 1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_two"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_face_black_24dp"
            android:title="Navbar 2" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_three"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_insert_drive_file_black_24dp"
            android:title="Navbar 3" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="Chestii">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_smoke"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_smoking_rooms_black_24dp"
                android:title="Smth" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: Paste the code you wrote so far, and it is better to provide a drawing rather than describing it.

Comment: It seems to me what you want is to have two different Tab bars really. So your Navbar1 shows Fragment1, which has the Tabbar showing different fragments, and Navbar2 shows Fragment2, which has another Tabbar, also showing different fragments.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I get the issue fully. If you merely want to change the String in a Tab's fragent based on the currently selected item in the Navbar, you could just build an interface to the fragment, providing that string when you select the menu item. Otherwise, you'll need to provide some code and further illustrate what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MikkelJørgensen i edited the post. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Anyone?..... ..